# upgrade from boost 1.48 to 1.49 has filesystem path Access violation reading location 0x0000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, boost-filesystem

My unit tests fail after upgrading boost to 1.49.  Same time place:

Stack:

```
msvcr100d.dll!_initerm
dynamic initializer for Foo::ourTempFolder
```

where `ourTempFolder` is a static class variable of `boost::filesystem::path`.

Null location is in:

`anonymous namespace::convert_aux()` which the comment says converting `const char*` to `wstring`

I have switched back to 1.48, rebuilt solution, everything fine.  Upgrade to 1.49, rebuilt, same problem.

Using Windows7 64 bit Visual Studio 2010 with SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a [bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6638) filed already.